# SOQL results correct result in query editor but getting blank values in API for same query

Tags: soql, api

We are facing issue while fetching the Training Event fields by using following query:

```
SELECT Id,Name,Training_Offering_Id__r.Delivery_Type__c,PEPE_Training_Request__c.Training_Offering_Id__r.Theater_Region__c,PEPE_Training_Request__c.Training_Offering_Id__r.Learning_Partner__c,Local_Contact_Number__c,Training_Location_City__c,ZIP_Code__c,Geography__c,PEPE_Training_Request__c.Training_Offering_Id__r.Technology__c,PEPE_Training_Request__c.Training_Offering_Id__r.Delivery_Team__c,Learning_Partner_Name__c,PEPE_Training_Request__c.Training_Offering_Id__r.Audience__c,Fiscal_Quarter__c,Language__c,PEPE_Training_Request__c.Training_Offering_Id__r.Program__c,CSAT_Score__c,Training_Offering_Id__c,PEPE_Training_Request__c.Training_Offering_Id__r.Name,Actual_Costs__c,PEPE_Training_Request__c.Training_Offering_Id__r.Platform__c 
FROM PEPE_Training_Request__c 
WHERE (Status__c='Event Approved') 
AND (Platform__c='Partner Plus') 
AND (CVENT_Flag__c='Yes') 
AND (CVENT_Status__c='Not Started')
```

We are able to run this query on SFDC developer console. However if we pass the same query from API we are getting the blank values for fields where we are using syntax like ‘PEPE_Training_Request__c.Training_Offering_Id__r.Theater_Region__c’.

Can you please look into it?

Comment: post your code.

Comment: Near impossible to tell the problem just by looking at the query. Kindly post your code and also stack trace or at least the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried updating your WSDL to ensure all new fields are there?
Does your users that you are logging in with have field level security visibility of these fields?